# How can I search within a manpage?

Tags: search, manpage

Is there a option to search within manpages?

Comment: Do you mean search within *all* the manpages to find which one has certain content, or search within *one* given manpage for a certain phrase?

Comment: @frabjous i meant within one manpage, is there also a option to search all?

Comment: I added that too. By the way, you can also type `man man` to read all of the technical details about man-pages.

Comment: The `man` for `man` that I am looking at, circa 2015 (I think it's Solaris... I know this is an Ubuntu board), does not mention searching using `/`, or anything else that can be done inside `man`. It has a bunch of command-line options and that's it.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Just hit <kbd>/</kbd>, and type your search pattern.

- Patterns can be [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex), for example, you could search for the word "option" by typing:

  ```
  /[Oo]ption
  ```

  Or find all of the long arguments with:

  ```
  /(--)[a-Z]
  ```

  To cancel the search, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

  Some useful quantification operators are:

  ```
    ?    for zero or one of the preceding expression
    *    for zero or more of the preceding expression
    +    for one or more of the preceding expression
  ```

  And expressions can be "grouped" with parentheses, as in `(--)+` (for two or more dashes).

  `[a-Z]` is a sequence (others include `[0-9]`, `[a-z]`, and so on). Sequences can be combined, as in `[a-Z0-9]`. You can also invert expressions with the `^` operator, e.g. `(--)[^a-Z]+` for all long arguments that start with anything other than a letter.

  Another useful operation is *Union* (`|`), as in `color|colour`, which finds every occurrence of either "color" or "colour" (this is sometimes called *boolean OR*).

  If you are searching for strings containing some of these "reserved" characters (like `?`, `*`, `+`), prefix them with a `\`  (i.e. `/\+k` to search for `+k`).
- To **jump through** the results, press <kbd>N</kbd> (forwards) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (backwards).
- There is also a way to search **across all manpages**:

  ```
  man -K "Hello World"
  ```

  The `man` program will open the first match, and after you close it with `q`, offer you to

  - view the current one (Return)
  - skip the current one (Ctrl+D)
  - or exit (Ctrl+C)

Comment: this depends on your `pager` alternative: `update-alternatives --display pager`. This is correct for `less`

Comment: is there also an option to browse through the results with a key? i.e. as in firefox you would press F3 and the cursor jumps from one result to the next?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it. Added it to the answer.

Comment: Another useful tip for `less`, instead of using `[oO][pP]...` for each character, use `-i` to toggle case sensibility.

Comment: Hmm Ctrl+C to cancel doesn't seem to work for me. Esc+U does though.

Comment: "Just hit /, and type your search pattern." I hit / on the numpad and nothing happens.

Comment: The viewer that `man` uses has a few vim-like key shortcuts, this is just one of them

Comment: What if I'm searching for `+i` how do I skip special character? @StefanoPalazzo

Comment: @Shayan you can "escape" these characters by prefixing them with a backslash; so to search for `+k`, you'd type `/\+k`, where `\+` means "literally a plus sign"

Comment: During the search all find word highlighted in same color. Is it possible to change the color of the current selected word during search? @StefanoPalazzo

Comment: Sorry to be the one to ask the stupid question, but where do I run `/searchterm`? E.g. if I want to search the git manual for 'remotes', I try: `man git /remotes` but it doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 18):

Minor appendix to the excellent answer from Stefano:

`man` uses `less` when no other pager specified. So you can search either with `/` or with `?`.

If you search with `/` then you search forward and you use `n` to find the next match and `N` to find previous match and if you search with `?` (search backward) `n` will search previous match and `N` will search the next match.

Use `man less` for the details.

Also you may use `man -wK word` to list out all manual files with some word.

Answer (score 8):

If you are already in the man page, `/` search is easy to use, but I prefer to specify my search word *with* the `man` command, so it opens directly on the first occurrence of the term.

This is fairly straight forward with a pipe:

```
man ksh | less +/LINENO
```

But if you wanted to stick only to `man` options, it seems to be very roundabout. You have to override the default output pager (`less -f`) with the `-P` option.

```
man -P 'less -p LINENO' ksh
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for! `man` should definitely have an option to search for a string from the command line built-in. Can `man ksh | less +/LINENO` be phrased in a way that doesn't mention `less`?

Answer (score 6):

## GUI Methods

If you have Ubuntu Desktop version installed you can search graphically.

### Gnome Help

Gnome help uses `yelp` program. Instead of typing `man ls` for the CLI man page you can type `yelp man:ls` and view in GUI window:

[image: yelp man:ls.png]

Once loaded you can use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search.

### Browser

I open the man page on the internet and use my browsers search feature <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

For example if in the terminal I type in `man yad` in my browser I would type `linux man yad`.

You sometimes need to pay attention that the internet version can sometimes have newer or older list of arguments but this has rarely happened to me.

The advantages of internet manpages goes beyond search facility and includes superior scrolling plus easier copying to clipboard.