# How to get help on a specific option of a command

Tags: command-line, bash, manpage

I guess the title says it all. I know I can get help on a specific command, for example `wget`, like this:

```
wget --help
```

But how can I get help on some specific option of that command? For example, I might want to find out about (and only about) `wget`'s `-A` option. You won't believe it, but an hour of googleing didn't help me on this question :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: man <command> should give you the information. In most cases, simply search google for `man <command>` gives you an online version.

Comment: @souravc : thanks for the link. I didn't know about the `/` command. That pretty much solved my problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use man pages in ubuntu

in the terminal type

```
man <command name>
```

eg: `man wget`

it will  shows up a detailed description of the command including options.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I knew about man-pages, but didn't know you could search them with `/`. Heard about it for the first time here [how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20752/how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage).  Well, problem solved, merci!