# Streaming a video using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I am using a 1080p video and 720p video using FFMPEG but the clarity of the video which is streamed is not matched with resolution of the video.so how should i give the parameters like frame per sec, scale,bit rate in FFMPEG command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I search within a manpage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20752/how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage) example: `man ffmpeg`

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ffmpeg.1.html

Comment: Show your command and the complete log.